# python shell import pandas

Tags: python-2.7, shell, python-3.x, pandas

I have been using pandas and numpy in the iPython Notebook for Python 2.7 and 3.5 without problems for some time.
Now I am switching to the Python Shell for some tasks, but when I type `import pandas` in the shell, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
ImportError: No module named 'pandas'
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason your python shell is using different environment variables that your ipython notebook. Could be due to various reasons, maybe you've installed python from the official website, and another distribution such as anaconda (happenned to me for this reason).

To check if that interpretation is correct, look ar the result of the following in both environment (shell & notebook)

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Most likely you will find different folders. Python can only import for *subfolders* of those folders. I guess some will be missing in your shell.

You have 3 approaches :

1. The easiest way out is to also use `ipython` for your default shell. It should have the same environment than the notebook.
2. If you really need `python` shell to use pandas (but there shouldnt a need), you'll have to add the missing python related folders to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable (how to do exactly depends on your OS, you should find easily by googling around). But it may be a pain.
3. Alternatively, you can start using virtual environments. You can use either `conda` or `virtualenv`. They allow you to create have different environements using different python libraries. It's a very useful skill to have with python. I suggest you to check this.

If you're doing data analytics / data science, use conda. Else use virtualenv.

- [starting with conda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html)
- [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)